Using degenerate primers for barcoding
I want to add DNA barcodes to the gene of interest (GOI) to identify a variant that yields high expression in neurons. I am planning to add barcodes to the 3' end of my gene so that I can use barcode counts as a proxy for counting GOI mRNA transcripts. My question is, can I use a degenerate primer with a well-defined handle to add random barcodes to my GOI? I saw some papers where they commercially synthesized barcodes. I understand that commercially synthesized barcodes have an advantage in that they would know the diversity beforehand, but it is also expensive. So, does anyone know if I can use degenerate primer for adding barcodes by PCR instead of synthesizing millions of barcodes? My forward primer will bind to the 5'end of my gene of interest, and the reverse primer will be something like this: 20bp 3'end specific sequence of GOI-degenerate nucleotides- a handle (Eg. AGCGTGGACGCTGATTCCAG-NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN-GCCATGGCAGCTTGCAGA). Has anyone used this type of strategy for barcoding DNA ? Will this work?

I'd guess (and it is a real guess) that you won't get true barcoding because you don't know if one or more of the primers are the same in the pool that you get from the supplier. The commercially synthesized ones you know the proportions of each in the pool a priori, but your plan you don't.
